# Relay and wifi module

Tags: switches, esp8266, home-automation

I'm a beginner in electronics and I am trying to do a "connected switch" with a relay and a wifi module ESP8266, but the thing is that to power the wifi module I need a second power supply and I find that pretty disappointing. I wondered if that was possible to integrate a 230v AC to 5v DC converter in the circuit to just take the power on the same cable. Sorry if my question is not very smart and thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Yes, you can try the 2-in-1 ESP8266 Relay: https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/4000129440350.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.f3671c41G3wnkr&algo_pvid=1cc58c5c-aec6-4997-84f5-6385cd5e0851&algo_expid=1cc58c5c-aec6-4997-84f5-6385cd5e0851-56&btsid=0bb0624016083792755294474e80a9&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Comment: There's a variety of 'smart switches' available from China - most are based on the esp8266. I can go to the local hardware store and by one for around $20AUD that also has a USB charge output. There's also a number of open-source firmware projects - like Tasmota that you can load onto these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there's enough "smart" switches that do that, the answer is clearly that it's possible. That answers your question, but let's be helpful instead of just correct:

You *still* shouldn't do that: when you use an external power supply, someone who knows electronics makes sure you're not getting killed. Building a 230 V switch-mode power supply isn't trivial, and so you'd either buying a industrial module (more expensive than a whole commercially available smart switch, or an external 5V supply) or building something that's dangerous if you have no education on building safe circuitry and a good understanding of electronics.

When you build this into your own design, it's your fault if you get electrocuted or your house burns down in your sleep. As a beginner's project maybe do something that doesn't involve 230 V; you're not building this for any productive usage, anyways. (if you plan to do exactly that: don't. A commercially available device would be much much cheaper due to the economics of scale than an equally safe device that any of us could build ourselves.)

Comment: Thanks a lot man, your honesty is the best answer I could get. I think you're right this is safer to buy one (this is just to connect to a vocal assistant I made in python ).